How was this fragment of Anaximander received?
What was the reception of Anaximander's fragment in antiquity?

From where things come into being, into there they also decay in accordance with necessity; for they pay damages and are penalized for their injustice in accordance with the order of time.


You can see Aristotle's Physics: he had the opportunity to read the original text.

Here's a possible lead: https://www.academia.edu/109409088/Stumbling_over_the_Boundary_Stone_of_Greek_Philosophy_Two_Centuries_of_Translating_the_Anaximander_Fragment

As the title of the academia lead above suggests (Stumbling over the 'Boundary Stone
of Greek Philosophy') the fragment is seen by several authors (Nietzsche...) as a boundary stone of early Greek philosophy over which one is still  stumbling. Yet, I find rather limited direct responses to it in ancient Greek literature. Did they already stumble too much over it to handle it? In its original Greek form, it gives an even more tragic feel associating δικη (justice) with φθορα (destruction,ruin).

Echoes of this feeling can be heard in Greek tragedies, as in the concluding words of Sophocles in The Women of Trachis: "Girls, you must not stay in this building, where you have seen dreadful deaths with many sorrows unheard of before -and none of these things were not Zeus". Here too this association of death and ruin with Zeus as the provider of δικη (justice). Whether this is a far echo of the Anaximander boundary stone remains open, but not impossible.
